# Django REST - send multiple querysets in one GET-Response

Tags: django, api, rest

My view currently accepts a username and  if the user exists it sends back a queryset of all entries in a Model, where the corresponding userid fits.
The Model UserProject consists of a UserID and a ProjectID, both are references to their own tables.
I would like to add the Project Model to the queryset.

my view:

```
class GetUserDataByNameView(
    APIView,
):
    def get(self, request, username):
        if User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
            uid = User.objects.get(username = username).id
            queryset = Userproject.objects.filter(user_id = uid)
            readSerializer = UserprojectSerializer(queryset, many = True)
            return Response(readSerializer.data)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data":"no user with this username"}, status = 200)
```

the Response currently looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:05:03.757807Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:05:03.762307Z",
        "user": 3,
        "project": 50
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:27:59.938422Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:27:59.945439Z",
        "user": 3,
        "project": 51
       #"projectname": (from ProjectID 51)
       #"projectDescriptor":
       #" other stuff from ProjectModel":
    }
]
```

So how would I insert the fields for the current Project ?
If I did some useless stuff in the code, please tell me. Newbie in Django

serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Project
from .models import Userproject

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length = 500, required = True)
    descriptor = serializers.CharField(max_length = 1000,  default = None)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

class UserprojectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Userproject
        fields = '__all__'
```

models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = None)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'projects'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name




class Userproject(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'UserProjects'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Comment: post the serializer and the model

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserprojectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Userproject
        fields = ['projects','id','user',]
```

You need to pass the `Project data` to your `UserProject Serializer`, also I have mentioned `many=True` because `User` is connected to `ForeignKey` so a user can have multiple `projects`.

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length = 500, required = True)
    descriptor = serializers.CharField(max_length = 1000,  default = None)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name','descriptor']
```

Comment: so do I use this to add some additional data to a serialized model in general ? 
How would I decide to not show the projects model when I serialize at an other view?

Comment: it depends on what you need, if the Model is connected then yes, else there are other ways to add data

Comment: I applied your changes. Nothing else, but it shows the exact same output. Do i need to specifically call it in the view?

Comment: can you try the updated code?

Comment: that gave me this
```
[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "user": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "user": 4
    }
]
```

Comment: could I add two models in the Meta class maybe?

Comment: can you update your both serializers according to the one I gave

Comment: same output as before

Comment: try this last thing, remove the read_only=True and try again

Comment: got an error :
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `projects` on serializer `GetUserDataSerializer`. (called it something else to have it isolated)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238514/discussion-between-exprator-and-nic0lodeon).